# How to make sidebar overlap the header?

Tags: css, html

I tried using z-index to make the sidebar overlap the header but am unable to do so.

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 0;
}

aside {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  z-index: 200;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header></header>
  <aside></aside>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define `position: absolute` for `.aside`

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

aside {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background-color: green;
 }
```

```html
<body>
  <header></header>
  <aside></aside>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to a prior question. Have you tried to use a negative margin with your sidebar to improve the overlap?

[How to overlap sidebar on top of nav-bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19919599/how-to-overlap-sidebar-on-top-of-nav-bar)

Try this:

```
header {

width: 100%;

height: 50px;

background-color: blue;

z-index: 0;

}


aside {

height: 100vh;

width: 300px;

background-color: green;

margin: -50px;

z-index: 200;

}
```

Comment: I found the answer actually [here](http://cssreset.com/z-indexnotworking/), z-index doesn't work with static positioning, it worked after I set `position` to `relative` for both `header` and `aside`. But your solution seem to work as well.

Comment: Glad to hear it. If it does help, please do select it as the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could add `position: absolute`

```
aside {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  z-index: 200;
}
```